# Sum and classify time entries per different time intervals with Java

Tags: java, date

I have a problem that involves some sort of work log and reporting. There are 5 users and I need to obtain their work hours between 2 dates.

I can do this and obtain a list of `WorkEntry` objects: each object has a name, start date, and end date.

I am unable to make the report show a monthly sum of the work entries per employee. Let's say I make a report for January to April. What I'm thinking is, for each of the 5 users:

- take the initial date and 'zero' on the day
- create a new date which is one month after the start date (February)
- sum app all the `WorkEntry` times that are between January and February
- place the sum in an array
- when no more `WorkEntry` between January and February, increase the dates by one month
- increase the array counter and repeat

I'm finding myself using 3 calendars, and my last step does not work properly if there is a month without work logs. Can I get some ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use Joda Library. It is better while working with dates.

Comment: Looks good, but you reckon the procedure mentioned is the best for my problem?